# Create Categorical Variable based on Maximum of Three Columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with sentiment probabilities for certain news articles that looks like this:

`sentimentPositive  sentimentNegative   sentimentNeutral
0.219640            0.010708            0.769652
0.539188            0.088198            0.372615
0.561837            0.264411            0.173752
0.570648            0.255499            0.173853
0.525263            0.097155            0.377582`

I now want to create a new categorical column that tells me, which sentiment in the row has the highest probability and encode it with e.g. (`0`, `1`, `2`) for the dominant sentiment.

The final output should look like:

`sentimentPositive  sentimentNegative   sentimentNeutral  Sentiment
0.219640            0.010708            0.769652          2
0.539188            0.088198            0.372615          0 
0.561837            0.264411            0.173752          0
0.570648            0.255499            0.173853          0
0.097155            0.525263            0.377582          1`

I know that I can get the max values of the columns by:

```
df["max"] = df[["sentimentPositive","sentimentNegative","sentimentNeutral"]].max(axis=1)
```

And could then compare the values in the `max` column to the other values to check the category. But there should be a more pandanic way to do it, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) for positions:

```
cols = ["sentimentPositive","sentimentNegative","sentimentNeutral"]
df["max"] = df[cols].values.argmax(axis=1)
#for columns names
#df["max"] = df[cols].idxmax(axis=1)
print (df)
   sentimentPositive  sentimentNegative  sentimentNeutral  max
0           0.219640           0.010708          0.769652    2
1           0.539188           0.088198          0.372615    0
2           0.561837           0.264411          0.173752    0
3           0.570648           0.255499          0.173853    0
4           0.097155           0.525263          0.377582    1
```